# System of stochastic differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

Is it possible to solve numerically system of coupled non-linear differential equations with noise?

The system looks like

```
x'[t][i] = A[i] + Sum[f[x[i][t],x[j][t]], {j, 1, M}] + n[i][t]
```

where `A[i]` is the positive `i`-dependent constant, `M` is the number of equations and `f=Sin[x[j]-x[i]]`. The noise term `n[i][t]` is the simple Gaussian noise with zero mean, $\langle n_i(t)\rangle =0$ (averaged by time) and $\langle n_i(t)n_j(t')\rangle = R\delta_{ij}\delta(t-t')$ where $R$ is the positive constant.

I am interested in numerical solutions of such system and would like to study dependence of solutions on parameters `A[i]` and `R`

Comment: Check out `ItoProcess`.

Comment: @ChrisK , it seems that it is enough. However, I do not understand clearly: in order to obtain $\langle n_i(t)n_j(t')\rangle=R\delta_{ij}\delta(t-t')$, should I set `n\[Distributed] WienerProcess[0,R]`?